# In javafx, how to change scrollbar arrow color?

Tags: css, javafx

i'm customizing scrollbar using css and I can't change the increment/decrement arrows color. In fact, it's simpler to change their form - like this:

```
.increment-arrow {
    -fx-shape: "M 0 0 L 4 8 L 8 0 Z";
}
```

But nothing I'm trying to add to that style can change the color of the arrows (the arrows themself, not the background around them).
How this could be implemented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at how modena styles the `ScrollBar` control you'll find out that the arrows use these rules:

```
.scroll-bar > .increment-button > .increment-arrow,
.scroll-bar > .decrement-button > .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-mark-highlight-color, derive(-fx-base,-45%);
}
```

so all you need to do is just override that color with your own:

```
.scroll-bar > .increment-button > .increment-arrow,
.scroll-bar > .decrement-button > .decrement-arrow {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

[image]

You can find the modena.css file included in the jfxrt.jar or listed in the openJFX [repository](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u/rt/file/1ba7759999ad/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css).